# erro html5 css3 elemento não fica com o que foi especificado

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

como posso fazer para que os elementos se mantenham conforme o primeiro elemento da coluna. pois os mesmos não estão conforme o desejado. no primeiro elemento eu tenho dois `icones` um de `heart` e um de `check`, porem estes mesmo não se repetem nas respectivas imagens. eles apenas aparecem rapidamente ao passar o mouse por cima da imagem. como faço para resolver este problema?

link da demo: https://jsfiddle.net/h69atvrc/2/

```css
h1, p{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
h1{
 color: #fff;
}
p{
 font-size: 1.05rem;
  color: #666;
}

.img-thumbnail{
 display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:none;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.hovereffect {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  /*min-height: 250px;*/
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:default;
  /*box-shadow:0px 3px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);*/
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
  transition:all .2s linear;
}

.hovereffect a.info {
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#fff;
  opacity:0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
  margin:50px 0 0;
}
.info:focus{
 outline: 0px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color
}
.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  opacity:1;
  
}

.clic{
 border-color: #13B8DC;
}
.clic:before{
 content: "\f00c";
 font:normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
 position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 1rem;
    left: 4px;
}

.hovereffect .clic{
 background-color: #13B8DC;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
}
.heart{
 background-color: #f36a5a;
 z-index: 1;
}

.heart:before{
 content: "\f004";
 font:normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
 position: absolute;
    top: 31px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    left: 4px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);

}
.hovereffect .heart{
 width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -80px;
    top: -25px;
}
.fixo{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0 !important;
 z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
   transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
 width: 100%;
 height: 65px;
 left: 0; 
}
.badge{
  background-color: #6c6c6c;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 20px;
}
.texto{
 margin-top: 13px;
 padding: 8px;
}
.h{
  top: 150px;
}
.men{
  top: 1rem;
}
#information{
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: -130px;
    color: #fff;
}
#information:hover, #information:focus, #information:active{
  cursor: pointer;
}
#log{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
#log:hover, #log:focus, #log:active{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sweet-alert{
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.sweet-alert button{
  webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow{
  border-left-color: #fff;
}
.tooltip-inner{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
.modal-content{
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.modal-header, .modal-footer{
  border: none;
}
.modal-body{
  padding: 0;
}
#load{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.star {
    visibility:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.star:before {
   content: "\f006";
   font:normal normal normal 22px/1 FontAwesome;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   color: #FBC02D;
   margin-top: -10px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -50px;
   visibility:visible;
}
.star:checked:before {
   content: "\f005";
   font:normal normal normal 22px/1 FontAwesome;
   top: 50%;
   color: #FBC02D;
   margin-top: -10px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -50px;
   position: absolute;
}
.fa-star:before{
  color: #FBC02D;
}
.lobibox-notify.lobibox-notify-error{
  background-color: rgb(245, 64, 58);
  border-color: rgb(245, 64, 58);
}
.lobibox-notify{
  box-shadow: none;
}
.lobibox-notify.notify-mini{
  min-height: 36px;
}
.lobibox-notify.notify-mini .lobibox-notify-title, .lobibox-notify.notify-mini .lobibox-notify-msg{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.comentarios:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.paddi{
  padding: 30px;
}


.ala {
  width: 100%;
  break-before: avoid;
  break-after: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#container {
  column-count: 5;
  column-gap: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="col-lg-12" id="container">
  <div class="ala col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-25">
    <span style="position: absolute;top: -25px;font-size:1rem;margin-left: -30px;color:#666;left: 50%;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;display:block" class="rate"> <input type="checkbox" name="star[]" class="star" value="1" id="star_1" checked>Favorita</span>
    <div class="hovereffect clic">
      <div class="clic" style="display:block"></div>
      <div class="heart"></div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg" alt="namePhoto">
      <div class="overlay">
        <a class="info test-popup-link" href="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg"></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary check active">
            <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="ck[]" checked value="1" id="ck_1"> <span class="che">Desmarcar</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ala col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-25">
    <span style="position: absolute;top: -25px;font-size:1rem;margin-left: -30px;color:#666;left: 50%;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;display:block" class="rate"> <input type="checkbox" name="star[]" class="star" value="1" id="star_1" checked>Favorita</span>
    <div class="hovereffect clic">
      <div class="clic" style="display:block"></div>
      <div class="heart"></div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg" alt="namePhoto">
      <div class="overlay">
        <a class="info test-popup-link" href="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg"></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary check active">
            <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="ck[]" checked value="1" id="ck_1"> <span class="che">Desmarcar</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ala col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-25">
    <span style="position: absolute;top: -25px;font-size:1rem;margin-left: -30px;color:#666;left: 50%;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;display:block" class="rate"> <input type="checkbox" name="star[]" class="star" value="1" id="star_1" checked>Favorita</span>
    <div class="hovereffect clic">
      <div class="clic" style="display:block"></div>
      <div class="heart"></div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg" alt="namePhoto">
      <div class="overlay">
        <a class="info test-popup-link" href="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg"></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary check active">
            <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="ck[]" checked value="1" id="ck_1"> <span class="che">Desmarcar</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ala col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-25">
    <span style="position: absolute;top: -25px;font-size:1rem;margin-left: -30px;color:#666;left: 50%;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;display:block" class="rate"> <input type="checkbox" name="star[]" class="star" value="1" id="star_1" checked>Favorita</span>
    <div class="hovereffect clic">
      <div class="clic" style="display:block"></div>
      <div class="heart"></div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg" alt="namePhoto">
      <div class="overlay">
        <a class="info test-popup-link" href="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg"></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary check active">
            <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="ck[]" checked value="1" id="ck_1"> <span class="che">Desmarcar</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ala col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-25">
    <span style="position: absolute;top: -25px;font-size:1rem;margin-left: -30px;color:#666;left: 50%;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;display:block" class="rate"> <input type="checkbox" name="star[]" class="star" value="1" id="star_1" checked>Favorita</span>
    <div class="hovereffect clic">
      <div class="clic" style="display:block"></div>
      <div class="heart"></div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg" alt="namePhoto">
      <div class="overlay">
        <a class="info test-popup-link" href="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg"></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary check active">
            <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="ck[]" checked value="1" id="ck_1"> <span class="che">Desmarcar</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ala col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-25">
    <span style="position: absolute;top: -25px;font-size:1rem;margin-left: -30px;color:#666;left: 50%;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;display:block" class="rate"> <input type="checkbox" name="star[]" class="star" value="1" id="star_1" checked>Favorita</span>
    <div class="hovereffect clic">
      <div class="clic" style="display:block"></div>
      <div class="heart"></div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg" alt="namePhoto">
      <div class="overlay">
        <a class="info test-popup-link" href="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg"></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary check active">
            <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="ck[]" checked value="1" id="ck_1"> <span class="che">Desmarcar</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ala col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-25">
    <span style="position: absolute;top: -25px;font-size:1rem;margin-left: -30px;color:#666;left: 50%;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;display:block" class="rate"> <input type="checkbox" name="star[]" class="star" value="1" id="star_1" checked>Favorita</span>
    <div class="hovereffect clic">
      <div class="clic" style="display:block"></div>
      <div class="heart"></div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg" alt="namePhoto">
      <div class="overlay">
        <a class="info test-popup-link" href="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg"></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary check active">
            <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="ck[]" checked value="1" id="ck_1"> <span class="che">Desmarcar</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ala col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-25">
    <span style="position: absolute;top: -25px;font-size:1rem;margin-left: -30px;color:#666;left: 50%;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;display:block" class="rate"> <input type="checkbox" name="star[]" class="star" value="1" id="star_1" checked>Favorita</span>
    <div class="hovereffect clic">
      <div class="clic" style="display:block"></div>
      <div class="heart"></div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg" alt="namePhoto">
      <div class="overlay">
        <a class="info test-popup-link" href="http://www.kvraudio.com/i/300x250.jpg"></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary check active">
            <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="ck[]" checked value="1" id="ck_1"> <span class="che">Desmarcar</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O que a primeira imagem tem que as outras tem que ter?

Comment: Poderia ser um pouco mais claro p.f.v?

Comment: tem aqueles icones no canto superior direito e esquerdo.

Comment: eles tem que ter os icones manter, mas tem alguma coisa errada que não esta mantendo somente no primeiro e no abaixo do primeiro

Comment: tipo se passar o mouse encima das `img` que nao sao iguais a primeira vai aparecer como que e para ficar bem rapidamente

Comment: Edita a pergunta e explica direito.

Comment: GilmarSantos editei a pergunta